# Phone Database Primary Key Issue

Tags: sql, database, primary-key, composite-key

I'm designing a database to hold phones, SIM cards, phone-SIM pairings, and a history of phone-SIM pairings. One phone can only be paired to one SIM card at one time.

My issue is trying to think of a primary key which will uniquely identify a phone-SIM pairing. I've currently got a *comp(ound|osite) key of IMEI and ICCID, but this would be relying on the user not adding a new entry which would break the one phone-one SIM rule.

I could use validation to enforce this rule on the device-SIM pairing table, but would this be bad practice?

Thanks in advance.

*I say this as I'm currently struggling to remember the difference between a compound and a composite key.

Comment: Compound key is one using more than one column. Composite is concatenation of multiple columns. The former can have issue, the latter is an issue.

Comment: A composite key is a key with more than one attribute. So is a compound key. In ER terminology however there is a subtle difference between the two, namely that a "compound key" is one whose attributes happen to include a key for some other entity. Use the term composite key unless you mean to refer to the specific ER concept of a compound key. See also: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/in-sql-is-it-composite-or-compound-keys

Answer (score 1):

If you want a history of pairings in the same table.
Then an identity primary key will do the job

After all I could move my sim from phone1 to phone2 and then back to phone1.

It's a bit naughty as re-keying the table could move you into an alternate universe...
There's an implicit assumption that pair_id increases in the time dimension. 
Something that could be broken by anything with CRUD access to the table.

You could add a datetime date_paired, but if I swapped my sims very quickly...
Good time for two tables, current and history me thinks.

Answer (score 1):

> My issue is trying to think of a primary key which will uniquely
>   identify a phone-SIM pairing. I've currently got a *comp(ound|osite)
>   key of IMEI and ICCID, but this would be relying on the user not
>   adding a new entry which would break the one phone-one SIM rule.

Well, you didn't say the requirement was one phone to one SIM. You said, "One phone can only be paired to one SIM card *at one time*." (Emphasis added.)

The pair of columns IMEI and ICCID *sounds* like a fine candidate key for this table. (I'm taking your word; I don't know that much about cell phones and SIM cards.) If you allow users to enter data in the first place, you have to have some business process--probably implemented in application code or SQL--to allow updates, regardless of whether the rule is "one phone/one SIM" or "one phone/one SIM at a time".

Why? Those values are hard to enter correctly.

There's nothing wrong with adding a surrogate ID number *after* you put the *real* candidate key in place. There's a lot wrong in adding a surrogate ID number *without* putting the *real* candidate key in place.